# Lord Saladin's Iron Banner shop - random perks?

Tags: destiny

This week the Iron Banner is back in Destiny, but I have a question about the way the loot he offers in his shop have 'random' perks.

If a weapon is on sale in his shop, and you can see the perks it has, is this the one you'd receive if you bought it?

I understand you can re-roll the perks if you aren't happy...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you see in the shop is what you will get. This is the same as every other vendor, he isn't any different.

The only difference he has is that you can reroll the perks by equipping the weapon and then an option will appear in his interface.

You do also get random perks if you get the weapon as a reward after a match rather than buying it. You probably already know this but I'm adding it for completion.

When rerolling via Iron Banner and when getting weapons from random drops (eg decoding engram) the element can be randomised as well if it is not kinetic.

Comment: Does weapon element also reroll (if any)?

Comment: Yup. Weapon element is included in what can be rerolled both when rerolling via Iron Banner or when getting a random weapon as a drop from engram or whatever. The obvious restriction is that if it is a kinetic damage weapon (ie non-elemental such as all non-raid primaries) then it has no chance of gaining an element. Also added this to answer for more completeness.

Comment: I absolutely love the Iron Banner for this reason. I have a perfectly rolled void sniper rifle from them (there are no void exotic snipers so this was the only way to get a high quality one) - it can also be a pain to obtain even a normal void sniper. In addition, I managed to roll a few of the rocket launchers from them as well. Overall, rerolling Iron Banner weapons is the bees knees, and it is the reason why you should *save all of your Motes of Light*, because it takes 1 Mote of Light per re-roll.